# Jasmine: reverting back prototype method after unit test

Tags: javascript, mocking, jasmine

To test a certain part of my code I need to mock out a prototype method to make sure it's called. The code looks something like this.

```
SomeObject.prototype.foo = jasmine.createSpy()
var so = SomeObject()
so.bar()
expect(SomeObject.prototype.foo).toHaveBeenCalled()
```

This works but it changes the state of the SomeObject which I don't want. So I was wondering is there a way to revert the state of prototype.foo after I am done? I was thinking maybe about making a copy of SomeObject. I took a look at jQuery.extend but I am not sure if I can use that to copy constructor functions.

Comment: You should specify which mocking library you're dealing with.

Comment: I've updated the title & tags to reflect that.

Comment: I updated my code a little too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two choices. It's preferable to spy on the instance:

```
spyOn(so, 'foo');
```

Or, if you insist that you want to verify that the prototype is called:

```
spyOn(SomeObject.prototype, 'foo');
```

Jasmine tears down all spies after each spec.

Answer (score 1):

```
delete SomeObject.prototype.foo;
```

in tearDown or just in the end of concrete test.